# I need to create a mailto link from PHP code

Tags: php, html, mailto

Ok, so at the moment my html form gathers data and posts it to a php form which then creates and sends an email (following code), however now I need the form to create a mailto link so I can send it to a different mail account from my iphone6, any help please???!!  :)

The code is:

```
<?php
ini_set( "SMTP", "localhost" );
ini_set( "smtp_port", "25" );

if ( isset( $_POST['caseref'] ) ) {

    $email_from = "dave@dave.com";
    $to = "dave@dave.com";
    $email_subject = "Arrival:  " . $_POST['caseref'];

    function died( $error ) {
        // error code here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error . "<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if ( !isset( $_POST['casreref'] ) ) {
        #died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $caseref = $_POST['caseref']; // required
    $notes = $_POST['notes']; // required

    $error_message = "";

    $email_message .= "Incident Number: " . $caseref . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Arrival Date:" . date( " d/m/Y " );
    $email_message .= "\n";
    $email_message .= "Arrival Time:" . date( "  H:i  ", time() );
    $email_message .= "\n";
    $email_message .= "Engineer:  " . $name . " \n";
    $email_message .= "Engineers Notes:  " . $notes;
    $email_message .= "\n";
    $email_message .= "\n";
    $email_message .= "\n";


    $headers = 'From: ' . $email_from;
    mail( $to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers );
    ?>
    <!-- include your own success html here -->
    <html>
        <title>Thank you!</title>

        Mailto link needs to go here

<?php
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me out with this at all please?

The email needs to look like:

> mailto: davey@dave.com
>
> subject: Arrival
>
> body: Incident Number:XXXXXX
>
> Arrival Date: 20/11/2015
>
> Arrival Time: 14:41
>
> Engineer: Dave
>
> Engineers Notes:

Comment: This is HTML 101 stuff.

Comment: it's just html, not rocket science. `echo '<a href="mailto:....">blahblah</a>';`

Comment: Can you show me please?  I cannot pass through the variables (output from the html form) into the HTML string.....sorry I didnt write this code and Im not a programmer!

Comment: `echo '<a href="mailto:....">*meh*</a>';`

Comment: I know mailto guys, but how do I parse the data from the page into the mailto link?

Comment: @DaveyH I'm not sure I completely understand...do you want to set the `subject` and `body` of the email within the `mailto` link?

Comment: If your sending $email_message you already have the data you need. mailto you can add subject and body. You can't have html in the body just newlines as you currently have. Just make sure to url encode it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we've been discussing, you need to use `NVP` in the `mailto` link. For your newline breaks to be respected, you need to use `urlencode()` or `rawurlencode()` depending on email clients and how they respect encoding.

```
$to = "dave@dave.com";
$caseref = "123";
$name = "Bob";
$notes = "Some notes";
$email_subject = "Arrival some data";
$email_message = "Incident Number: " . $caseref . "\n";
$email_message .= "Arrival Date:" . date("d/m/Y");
$email_message .= "\n";
$email_message .= "Arrival Time:" . date("H:i");
$email_message .= "\n";
$email_message .= "Engineer:  " . $name . " \n";
$email_message .= "Engineers Notes:  " . $notes;
$email_message .= "\n";
$email_message .= "\n";
$email_message .= "\n";

// Echo the mail to link
echo '<a href="mailto:'.$to.'?subject='.urlencode($email_subject).'&body='.urlencode($email_message).'">Mail to Link</a>';

// Echo the mail to link using the different encoding
echo '<a href="mailto:'.$to.'?subject='.rawurlencode($email_subject).'&body='.rawurlencode($email_message).'">Mail to Link</a>';
```

Also note: I've removed the `time()` from your `date()` function since by default `time()` is used...specifying it is not necessary.

Comment: Incident+Number:+test 
Arrival+Date:+20/11/2015+ 
Arrival+Time:++17:00++ 
Engineer:++Dave+Hawkes 
Engineers+Notes:++On+site 

Nearly there!  How do we remove the ++++

Comment: The `+` is used where spaces are and comes from the function `urlencode()` which is required. When you click the link and it opens in your mail application, it will remove the encoding.

Comment: It doesnt remove the +'s when I click the link

Comment: It is likely the email client then. Try replacing the `urlencode()` functions with `rawurlencode()`.

Comment: @DaveyH did that resolve the issue with the email client?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am checking now and will let you know shortly :)

Comment: It did indeed!  Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @DaveyH great to hear! May I ask that if this solved your problem, you mark it as the answer. The currently marked answer, although helpful, does not appear to be a correct answer.

Comment: Sorry this is my 1st post and Im a noob at web dev!  Think Ive marked it as correct now!  Just one last thing if you may help, when the page loads I need it to auto click the mailto link, ive looked at some jscripts but cant get it to work with the php variables.....any ideas?

Comment: If you are using the `jQuery` library then `$("#linkId").click();` would work. Note that it must be triggered after the page has loaded, so wrap it in `$(function(){ });`. If this does not work, probably best to start a new question and let me know and we can solve it there so we don't pollute this question/answer.

Comment: Will try it as soon as I can, thank you very much for your help on this, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
   <!-- Mailto link needs to go here-->
<?php echo'<a href="mailto:'.$to.'" subject="'.$email_subject.'" body="'.$email_message.'>Send mail</a>';?>
```

Comment: This isn't how `mailto` works...it's `NVP` like `mailto:nowhere@mozilla.org?subject=Newsletter` taken from [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Email_links)

Comment: My bad !  Try   `echo '<a href="mailto:'.$to.'?subject='.$email_subject.'&body='.$email_message.'">Send umail</a>';` instead.

Comment: You're on the right lines though, anything else we're missing?  All the above gets me is:

TO: '.$to.'
Subject: '.$email_subject.'
Body: '.$email_message.'

Comment: You need the `<?php ?>` like so `<?php echo '<a href="mailto:'.$to.'?subject='.$email_subject.'&body='.$email_message.'">Send umail</a>'; ?>`

Comment: That works but it doesnt put a return in the body, so it looks like this now: 

Incident Number: djhArrival Date: 20/11/2015 Arrival Time:  16:16  Engineer:  Dave Hawkes Engineers Notes:  On site


but needs to look like:

Incident Number: djh
Arrival Date: 20/11/2015 
Arrival Time:  16:16  
Engineer:  Dave Hawkes 
Engineers Notes:  On site

Comment: Thank you so much Axel R!  This works! Just need a return after each variable :|

Comment: Also make note that you must `URL encode` the variables. Use `urlencode($email_message)` etc.

Comment: I understand its not the neatest bit of code, but can anyone tell me how I get a return after each variable?  Thanks

Comment: Try replacing the ` \n ` by `<br />`

Comment: that gets me: 

Incident Number: test<br />Arrival Date: 20/11/2015 <br />Arrival Time:  16:47  <br />Engineer:  Dave <br />Engineers Notes:  On site

Comment: @DaveyH  this is because you cannot use html in `mailto`. Please see my answer, it should solve your issue.

Comment: @camelCase - Can you elaborate please?!  I dont understand!

Comment: @DaveyH elaborate on which part? Have you tried my answer (not in these comments, the answer I posted separately)?