# PHP can't open outlook to send email

Tags: php, email, iis, outlook

I am trying to send an email from php, I CAN'T USE SMTP or normal ways of sending email because smtp servers are blocked on my network. I have outlook 2016 installed on my server machine (windows 10 IIS) and found this code to use outlook to send email from php but it dosen't work.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$subject="This is a test message";        
$message="This is a Body Section now.....! :)";        
$to="someaddress@somedomain.com";

// starting outlook        
com_load_typelib("outlook.application"); 

if (!defined("olMailItem")) {define("olMailItem",0);}

$outlook_Obj = new COM("outlook.application") or die("Unable to start Outlook");

//just to check you are connected.        
echo "Loaded MS Outlook, version {$outlook_Obj->Version}\n";        
$oMsg = $outlook_Obj->CreateItem(olMailItem);        
$oMsg->Recipients->Add($to);
$oMsg->Subject=$subject;        
$oMsg->Body=$message;        
$oMsg->Save();        
$oMsg->Send();    
?>
```

I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `outlook.application': Access is denied. ' in C:\Website2\test.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\Website2\test.php(13): com->com('outlook.applica...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Website2\test.php on line 13
```

Comment: You are getting an access denied exception. Maybe you cannot run outlook with the IIS user?

Comment: I can't really see any reason, why someone should block smtp, but allow mail "sending" through php via an outlook library. Ask for freeing that smtp chanel and then use PHPMailer. Which really works very good. In combination with Outlook too. As for Outlook, don't forget: it's a client program. You can do the following right now: use php to build a normal "mailto" anchor. Then make Outlook your default mail editor. Click on the link from HTML, Outlook opens.... et voila.

Comment: See: [this](http://subinsb.com/send-mails-via-smtp-server-gmail-outlook-php), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829678/i-need-to-create-a-mailto-link-from-php-code) and [this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). With PHPMailer you have POP too.